# Getting List of users who reacted on a message with a certain emoji

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This piece of code returns `Collection [Map] {}`.
Am I doing anything wrong?

```
c.messages.fetch(msgId).then(m => {
    var users = m.reactions.cache.get('').users.cache
    console.log(users)
})
```

Comment: You'll need to provide just a little more context for us to help you. For starters, what is the function definition for  `c.messages.fetch`?  What is `m.reactions.cache.get`? What do those functions return?

Comment: Are you trying to always track reactions on a specific message?

Comment: @Syntle Not Always, This Chunk of code is called at a specific time

Comment: Could you please edit your question to better explain your problem? What exactly is returning `Collection [Map] {}`?